# How can I review 'git diff' of staging change in git eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, gitx

I am using git plugin in eclipse.
How can I view the difference in each file in my staging area in git?

In Mac OS X Gitx too, I can see the differences of each staging/unstaging file.

How can I do the same in eclipse git?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `git staging view` in Eclipse. There you see staged and unstaged changes. By double clicking you can see the differences to the index or working tree.

Also you can do Rightclick > Compare with ... on the package explorer and select the version you want to compare the file to.